# How do I check the first class member from an .class and use hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a function that let's me hover over specific class members:

```
function cIf(element){

    if($(element+"[1]" + ":hover").length != 0){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }

}
```

and I am getting this :
Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: hover

when I call this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).click(function(){
        if(cIf(".myNav")){
            alert($(".myNav").html());
        }
    })
});
```

I don't know how to check for a specific class member and use :hover on him x.x
here is my html, maybe this helps :

```
<div class='myNav'>Home</div>
<div class='myNav'>Market</div>
```

I only want it to work when I click on home, If I remove the [1] it works on all elements and I don't want that...

Comment: what is the logic behind [1]?

Comment: What is your goal? There might be an entirely better way to go about this. The way you have this now, you're listening to any click event on the document and trying to check if an element in your navigation is hovered at that time? Can't you just use `$( ".myNav" ).hover()` instead of `$(document).click()`?

Comment: I want to get the alert if I click on the first elemenent, not the last not the 3rd,there are 10 elements in the class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to get the alert if I click on the first elemenent, not the
>   last not the 3rd,there are 10 elements in the class.

You could do something like this, try it out and see if this gets you what you want:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".myNav li").click(function() {
    if ($(this).closest("ul").children(":first").html() === $(this).html()) {
      alert($(this).html());
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myNav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This will work even if you have nested lists (like drop down navs) and you don’t have to hardcore the values to check for like the other answer (checking if the value is “Home” for instance)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a better answer,I am sorry:

```
function cIf(element,elementNumber){
    if($(element + ":nth-child("+elementNumber+")" + ":hover").length != 0){
        return true;    
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".myNav").click(function(){
        if(cIf(".myNav",1)){
            alert("hi");
        }

    })
});
```